# Laravel 5.4, AJAX Not Erroring When it Should

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been trying to follow quite a few different articles on how to deal with AJAX requests in Laravel. They're all different..

I have one that is finally not throwing me a 500 error, but it actually does not throw validation errors in the way you'd think.

My code will always default to the AJAX success part, not the error part, and display a "Success" in the console but also display the error JSON thrown back by my controller.

I have no idea what's going on my dudes. If you could help me out, it would be much appreciated!

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $rules = array(
                "name"      => "required|string|unique:brands|max:255",
                "contact"   => "string|max:255",
                "email"     => "string|max:255",
                "phone"     => "max:12"
            );

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                return \Response::json(array(
                    "errors" => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                // Submit to the database
                $brand = new Brand();

                $brand->name        = $request->name;
                $brand->contact     = $request->contact;
                $brand->email       = $request->email;
                $brand->phone       = $request->phone;
                $brand->created_by  = auth()->user()->id;
                $brand->updated_by  = auth()->user()->id;

                $brand->save();

                return \Response::json($brand);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return \Response::json(array("error" => "response was not JSON"));
        }
    }
```

**Route**

```
// Brands
Route::get('/brands', 'BrandsController@index')->name('brands');
Route::post('/brands/store', 'BrandsController@store');
```

**AJAX (Embedded via {{ Html::script() }})**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
    * Save a new brand to the database via AJAX
    */
    var url = "/brands/store";

    $("#save").click(function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {
            name:       $('#name').val(),
            contact:    $('#contact').val(),
            email:      $('#email').val(),
            phone:      $('#email').val(),
        }

        var type = "POST";

        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({

            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error: ", data);
                console.log("Errors->", data.errors);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

**HTML (Snippet, as it is a modal)**

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-create">
    <div class="modal-background" onclick="modal('#modal-create', 'close');"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="modal-create-results"></div>
        <h4 class="title is-4">
            Create a Brand
        </h4>
        <form id="create_brand" name="create_brand" class="form" novalidate="">
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                {{ Form::label("name", "Name", ["class" => "field-label is-normal"]) }}
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control">
                            {{ Form::text('name', null, ["class" => "input", "id" => "name", "required" => "required", "autofocus" => "autofocus"]) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                {{ Form::label("contact", "Contact", ["class" => "field-label is-normal"]) }}
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control">
                            {{ Form::text('contact', null, ["class" => "input", "id" => "contact"]) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                {{ Form::label("email", "Email", ["class" => "field-label is-normal"]) }}
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control">
                            {{ Form::email('email', null, ["class" => "input", "id" => "email"]) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                {{ Form::label("phone", "Phone", ["class" => "field-label is-normal"]) }}
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control">
                            {{ Form::text('phone', null, ["class" => "input", "id" => "phone"]) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                <p class="control is-grouped">
                    {{ Form::button("Save", ["type" => "submit", "class" => "button is-stenton", "id" => "save"]) }}
                    <a class="button" onclick="modal('#modal-create', 'close');">Cancel</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close" onclick="modal('#modal-create', 'close');"></button>
</div>

<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
{{ Html::script('js/brands/create_ajax.js') }}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a full url in the ajax post settings? Also try using data like this `data: {
              name: name,
              contact: contact,
              email: email,
              phone: phone,
              
          },`

Comment: Is response always going to success?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I had tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @PankajMakwana It was always going to success. I have used apokryfos's method below and it worked.

Comment: are you getting validation messages?

Comment: @PankajMakwana I am now, they are coming in through xhr.responseText. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to just display "for each error in xhr.responseText". Right now, I have to manually check if (xhr.responseText["name"]) { ... }. bit annoying.

Comment: can you show me the validation errors?

Comment: I'm getting the standard Laravel validation errors. Show in the xhr.responseText here: {"name":["The name field is required."],"contact":["The contact must be a string."],"email":["The email must be a string."]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is always a success because you always send a successful response, even when it has errors included.

You have three choices in what to do:

1) Send the error code manually

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails())  {
    //422 is the standard error code laravel uses for validation errors so we're going to keep it
    return \Response::json(array("errors" => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()),422);
}
```

2) Let laravel handle it (recommended)

```
$this->validate($request,$rules); //Laravel will generate the appropriate error exception response
```

*`$this->validate` comes from the trait `ValidatesRequests`

3) Not recommended: keep the controller code as is and change your AJAX code to:

```
 $.ajax({

        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.errors) { /* errors happened */ } 
            else { /* no errors happened */ }
        }
 });
```

Not recommended because handling errors in a success handler is just wrong.

Comment: I went with #2, works! And now I can catch errors and display them by adding the responseText and calling that. Thank you so much! +1!

Comment: @WilliamDrake #2 is the laravel suggested way so that's a good call

Comment: Do you have any idea how I'd implement something like: foreach (xhr.responseText as error) { display_error_here }. Right now I have to check like this: if (xhr.responseText["name"]) { // exists, display error } for each field that is validated.

Comment: `for (var key in xhr.responseText) { alert("Field:"+key+" has error "+ xhr.responseText[key]); }` or even better `$.each(xhr.responseText, function (key, value) { /* do stuff here */ });`

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I think maybe my JSON response isn't correct, as this is what I'm getting back: {"name":["The name field is required."],"contact":["The contact must be a string."],"email":["The email must be a string."]}. This means that every character is a key, and I had 124 alerts to deal with :)

Comment: I think you need to do `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` to get it into an object.

Comment: Thanks mate. I ended up winning with var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)["errors"]; then using $.each to display the values. Cheers!